# How to make a picture appear after 5 seconds in Microsoft Visual C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want this image timer to appear after 5 seconds but don't know how to do it. So far I have made the image bounce around the form but I want the image to appear while bouncing after 5 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Bounce
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int horiz, vert, step;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //image is moved at each interval of the timer

            goblin.Left = goblin.Left + (horiz * step);
            goblin.Top = goblin.Top + (vert * step);


            // if goblin has hit the RHS edge, if so change direction left
            if ((goblin.Left + goblin.Width) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Width - step))
                horiz = -1;

            // if goblin has hit the LHS edge, if so change direction right
            if (goblin.Left <= step)
                horiz = 1;

            // if goblin has hit the bottom edge, if so change direction upwards
            if ((goblin.Top + goblin.Height) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Height - step))
                vert = -1;

            // if goblin has hit the top edge, if so change direction downwards
            if (goblin.Top < step)
                vert = 1;
        }


        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Soon as the forms loads activate the goblin to start moving 
            //set the intial direction
            horiz = 1;  //start going right
            vert = 1;   //start going down
            step = 5;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i mean i want the picture to appear after 5 seconds

Answer (score 3):

this should do it.

```
using System.Timers; // this is Where the timer class lives.

Timer fiveSecondTimer = new Timer(5000);
fiveSecondTimer.Elapsed += () => { ShowImageHere }; //This is short hand 
fiveSecondTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Can you you add this bit of code into my code please :)

Comment: I think it would be more beneficial to you to put it in your code. You have 3 methods. This will work inside any of those methods. however your tick method will create a new timer each tick so that is not recommended. you will also need to start with your image hidden.

Comment: what am i variable name is fiveSecondTImer? i mean is it an int, float etc. i am only a novice as i have to create a simple game.

Comment: fiveSecondTimer is a Timer() variable. You will need to add this useing statement to the top of your page to be able to use it: 
using System.Timers; 
if it starts with the new keyword then it is most likely going to be a class. so this code tell you that:
new Timer(5000)

Answer (score 0):

Create a private variable named `startTime`. Set it's value to `DateTime.Now` when you start the timer. Each time the timer ticks you can check whether the difference between the current `DateTime.Now` and the stored `startTime` and see if it's over 5 seconds.

```
int horiz, vert, step;
DateTime startTime;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timeElapsed = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds; // Show image if this is greater than 300       
    //image is moved at each interval of the timer

    goblin.Left = goblin.Left + (horiz * step);
    goblin.Top = goblin.Top + (vert * step);


    // if goblin has hit the RHS edge, if so change direction left
    if ((goblin.Left + goblin.Width) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Width - step))
        horiz = -1;

    // if goblin has hit the LHS edge, if so change direction right
    if (goblin.Left <= step)
        horiz = 1;

     // if goblin has hit the bottom edge, if so change direction upwards
    if ((goblin.Top + goblin.Height) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Height - step))
        vert = -1;

    // if goblin has hit the top edge, if so change direction downwards
    if (goblin.Top < step)
        vert = 1;

}

private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Soon as the forms loads activate the goblin to start moving 
    //set the intial direction
    horiz = 1;  //start going right
    vert = 1;   //start going down
    step = 5;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: This will probably work but the `Timer` solution is much more elegant.

Comment: is it possible that you could do it for me ?

Comment: i will really appreciate it if someone could send me the code with the 5 second timer in please

Comment: @user3574319: We will not write your program for you.  What don't you understand? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: i dont know where i am putting the code and  what varible is startTime

Comment: i dont know where i am putting the code and  what varible is startTime for exapme is it int startTime, float startTime? i am only a novice at programming and i need to build a game and this will help me a lot thank you

Comment: `startTime` should be `DateTime`and you should declare it in the beginning of the class.

Comment: what am i declaring startTime as... this is the part which i dont understand am i declaring it as a int or string

Comment: i dont know where i am putting this :/ i am really confused as i am only a novice

Comment: one more thing the picture doesnt appear after 5 seconds as it already starts moving ?

Answer (score -1):

My first instinct was to say to use Thread.Sleep(), but I wonder if that's going to work for you, since it seems like you don't want to block the whole execution for 5 seconds.

I see you're already using a Timer object to control the game loop of this goblin fellow. Is there any reason you can't just have another Timer that has an Interval of 5 seconds, and once it ticks, call Stop on it to prevent any future tick events, and start the goblin on his journey?

Comment: I dunno, if I want things to stop for like, 5 seconds, seems like a good idea. It wouldn't work here because this is a game, of course.